# can i handle android ANR? and change msgdialog?

Tags: android, media-player

there are ANR when I play some net clip, and I can't handle the error msg from MediaPlayer.
Can I handle ANR msg from system and change the  dialog? the default dialog is not comfort to user.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot handle ANR in your own application. You should try your best to avoid the ANR.

According to Android dev guide pages, the ANR is triggered by the following conditions:

1. No response to an input event (such as key press or screen touch events) within 5 seconds.
2. A BroadcastReceiver hasn't finished executing within 10 seconds.

So, you should look cat the logcat traces and the ANR traces to target the position where ANR occurs and check the source code to find any possible 'long-running operations' that might be blocking the main thread.

Try to use AsyncTask to carry the task in the background to avoid ANR, which is recommend by Android official site. Take the downloading for example:

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
    // Do the long-running work in here
    protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        int count = urls.length;
        long totalSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
            publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
            // Escape early if cancel() is called
            if (isCancelled()) break;
        }
        return totalSize;
    }

    // This is called each time you call publishProgress()
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
    }

    // This is called when doInBackground() is finished
    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        showNotification("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
    }
}
```

To execute this worker thread, simply create an instance and call execute():

```
new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
```

Comment: yes , i do. but in my app, I use MediaPlayer to play some online clip, and when some error happend(the most is clip can't play due to some reason) ,I can't handle from MediaPlayer, and which will make ANR.

Comment: What is the exactly the code that causes ANR? Are you calling mediaPlayer.prepare() to handle the remote content? Try prepareAsync() instead.

Comment: i used prepareAsync.what ever, I know I can't handle ANR but fixed them. thanks

Comment: Technically my answer answered your question, would you mind accept it?

Comment: It's NOT the answer to his question. The MediaPlayer object in Android is garbage and will block the main thread for many tasks, especially if dealing with remote content. prepareAsync does NOT fix this. You have just provided generic information that does not apply to this situation.

Comment: I did answered all his question. If you think the original media player is not good enough, you can send him your own made one. OK, it doesn't matter, I don't care.